# MSYS2: Command works fine in terminal, but syntax error `(' in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mingw, msys

On Windows, with MSYS2, I want to add the file extension for an executable back to the output of `which`, if it has one. Here's a one-liner:

```bash
locAlt="$(which "mingw32-make")" ; echo "$locAlt" ; locAlt=("$locAlt"+(|.*)) ; echo "$locAlt"
```

When run in the MSYS2 MinGW terminal, this works just fine on my machine and prints:

```bash
/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make
/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe
```

However, now I put the same line into a script (`one-liner.sh`):

```bash
#/bin/bash
locAlt="$(which "mingw32-make")" ; echo "$locAlt" ; locAlt=("$locAlt"+(|.*)) ; echo "$locAlt"
```

I tried both `nano` and `Notepad++` (where you can choose line endings, and they're set to "UNIX (LF)", and checked the output of `cat -v one-liner.sh`, which shows the file as above (no `^M`, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886144/why-is-a-shell-script-giving-syntax-errors-when-the-same-code-works-elsewhere)).
However, when trying to run the file with `./one-liner.sh`, I get the error

```bash
./one-liner.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./one-liner.sh: line 2: `locAlt="$(which "mingw32-make")" ; echo "$locAlt" ; locAlt=("$locAlt"+(|.*)) ; echo "$locAlt"'
```

Why could that be?

Comment: How the heck does that work without escaping the quotes inside the quotes?

Comment: I don't think the outer quotes survive the subshell. If you leave them out, anything inside the parentheses is expanded without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33925340) applies. Adding `shopt -s extglob` to the script makes it work. Apparently, the syntax `+(`... already falls under "extended globbing".